# Добавление независимой линии на график Chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

Занимаюсь создание графика, на котором показывается соотношение продаж определенного товара в определенной стране. Сейчас потребовалось на этот график добавить также линию средней цены данного товара. Столкнулся с проблемой того, что масштаб линий слишком сильно различается. За взятый срок в выбранной стране может быть продано от 5-6 тысяч товара в день, а средняя цена продажи будет равна примерно 10-14 руб. Из-за такой разницы в размерах данных линия средней цены отображается слишком низкой и без видимых изменений(скриншот)
[image: График chart.js]

Вопрос в следующем - как заставить график отрисовать данную линию цены адекватно(в идеале - посередине и с видимыми изменениями). Цена в среднем за день меняется на 0.5-0.6, понятно, что в сравнении с изменениями продаж на графике эти изменения совершенно мизерные.
Код графика:

```js
                            let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                                type: 'line',
                                data: {
                                    labels: data.dates,
                                    datasets: dataset,
                                },
                                options: {
                                    responsive: true,
                                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                                    scales: {
                                        yAxes: [{
                                            ticks: {
                                                beginAtZero: true
                                            }
                                        }],
                                        xAxes: [{
                                            ticks: {
                                                beginAtZero: true
                                            }
                                        }]
                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Разместить среднюю цену продажи на дополнительной оси, которую разместить например справа

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]